# How to calculate the BigO of these questions

Tags: big-o

I'm currently learning the Algorithm Analysis and have some questions cant figure it out

```
i=1
while (i<=n)
  i = i*3
```

And my answer is O(log base3 n), but the answer is O(log n)

```
sum = 1
for( i=0;sum<n;++i) sum+=1;
```

I know the sum = 1,2,3,5,8...  but how to determine the BigOtime.

```
for(i=1;i<n-1;++i)
   for(int j=n;j>=i;--j)
      statement
```

this question asks me to solve the execution times, so the external loop is n-2 times and the inner loop is n times? the answer is (n+3)(n-2)/2, I can't figure out

Comment: How did you come up with the answer O(log base3 n) ?

Comment: For that second loop - the value of `sum` is not 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ..., but rather 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., with the code you've written. Can you elaboate on how you arrived at 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ... ?

Comment: now I realize that I misread the sum. so let k be the run times, 1+2+...k <n and the answer will be O(n^1/2) ?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, O(log base3 n) is correct (I think) but it is written in Big O Notation as O(log n) regardless of the base. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Logarithmic_time)

For your second question, the outer loop runs `(n-2)` times. The inner loop, for each `i` will run `n-i+1` times. Summing this up for each `i` will be `n-1+1 + n-2+1 + n-3+1 + ... + n-(n-2)+1` which simplifies to `n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 3`. Using the sum of arithmetic series formula you will get `(n+3)(n-2)/2`.

Comment: the second program as the same using the sum of arithmetic series formula 1+2+...+k<n, so the answer is  O(n^1/2)?

Comment: Your second program is a for loop from 1-n, so it has complexity O(n) .